# How to integrate SkyWalking into tomcat and set the corresponding service name for each service of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, skywalking

I am trying to integrate SkyWalking into tomcat.Multiple services can be deployed in Tomcat. How to set Skywalking server name for each service?

The following is a solution I saw online, but it doesn't work.Only test2 will always be retained.

set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:D:\Tools\apache-skywalking-apm-8.9.0\agent\skywalking-agent.jar=agent.service_name=test1,agent.service_name=test2
or
set "CATALINA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\Tools\apache-skywalking-apm-8.9.0\agent\skywalking-agent.jar=agent.service_name=test1,agent.service_name=test2"